# Как отследить положение телефона в пространстве?

Tags: java, android

Мое приложение будет делать снимки и мне нужно чтоб пользователь держал телефон ровно. И если положение телефона не соответствует условию то будет появляться тост на экране.

1)Как отследить положение телефона?

2)и как это правильно называется?

Я знаю, что это используется в играх, когда едет машина допустим и юзер поворачивает телефон вправо или влево и приложение реагирует на это...

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется вам нужен Акселерометр. Тут как раз [туториал](http://mobile-developer.ru/uncategorized/rabota-s-akselerometrom-v-android-2/), попробуйте!

Comment: У меня тут такая проблема я использую акселерометр, но он я так понял определяет положение телефона относительно сторон света(Север, юг и т.д) и плюс использует магнитные поля (Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD), и из-за этого мои показатели всегда изменяются +/- на 10 в разные стороны... хотя девайс стоит на месте... Может есть способ точно измерить положение осей X Y Z? Может ли гироскоп дать такую возможность? Чтоб если телефон стоит на месте то показатели не прыгают и правильно отображаются

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/orientation.php). В данной статье есть ответы на оба вопроса

Comment: У меня тут такая проблема я использую акселерометр, но он я так понял определяет положение телефона относительно сторон света(Север, юг и т.д) и плюс использует магнитные поля (Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD), и из-за этого мои показатели всегда изменяются +/- на 10 в разные стороны... хотя девайс стоит на месте... Может есть способ точно измерить положение осей X Y Z? Может ли гироскоп дать такую возможность? Чтоб если телефон стоит на месте то показатели не прыгают и правильно отображаются